# What are the minimum machine specifications necessary for Admin and Container processes?

Tags: spring-xd

The reference material simply states that [JDK7 is required for Spring XD](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#_requirements).

What are the minimum requirements (RAM, CPU, Disk) for hosts meant to run Spring XD Admin?

What are the minimum requirements (RAM, CPU, Disk) for hosts meant to run Spring XD Containers?

Comment: This might be a good question for the [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) community as well.  There are a lot of experts with experience configuring and managing systems for a variety of different tasks over there and they would probably have some valuable input.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in both cases is it depends what you need to use them for.  It seems like Spring XD is designed for high throughput computing(HTC), so unlike traditional high performance computing the addition of GPUs or coprocessors in this case would probably not be particularly beneficial.  If you just want to try it out and happen to have several servers laying around it seems like as long as you have something that is powerful enough to run an OS that supports Java you could probably at least make it work.  If you are in the initial stages of testing Spring XD to see if it will integrate with your existing infrastructure this would allow you to at least try it out.  If you have passed that stage of testing and are confident that Spring XD will work and would like to purchase hardware to optimize its performance feel free to continue reading.

I have not used Spring XD before, but based on the documentation I have been reading and some experiences with HTC there are a few considerations for setting up systems to run it.  if you take a look at the [diagram](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/images/distributed-runtime-overview.png) from the docs and read a little bit about the services it seems like the Admin, Zookeeper, Analytics Repo and Batch Job DB could be hosted on virtual machines(VMs) under the hypervisor of your choice.

Using a setup with several of the subsystems required to use the distributed model running on VMs would give you the ability to scale resources as necessary, e.g. to begin a single hypervisor system may be sufficient to run everything but as traffic/use grows it may be desirable to separate the VMs onto multiple hypervisors and give some of the VMs additional resources.

With the containers it seems like many other virtualization or containerization schemes for HTC, where more powerful systems e.g. lots of RAM, SSD storage, allow users to run more containers on a single physical box.

To adequately assess the needs for a new system running any application it is important to understand what the limiting factor on the problem is; is it memory bound, IO bound or CPU bound?  For large scale parallel applications there are a variety of tools for profiling code and determining where bottlenecks occur.  [TAU](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/news.php) is a common profiling utility in HPC and there are several proprietary offerings available as well.

Once the limitations of the program are clear specing out a system with hardware to reduce/minimize the issue is a lot easier, and normally less expensive.  Hopefully this information is helpful.

Additions based on comments:

It seems like it *would* run with 128k of memory if you have an OS that will boot and run java and any other requirements.  If there is backend storage setups somewhere, like a standalone DB server which can be used for the databases as described in the DB Config section of the guide it seems like only a small amount of storage would be necessary.

Depending on how you deploy the images for the Admin OS that may not even be necessary as you could use [KIWI](http://doc.opensuse.org/projects/kiwi/doc/) to create and deploy a custom OS image of your choosing with configuration files and other customizations embedded in the image.  This image could be loaded via the network over PXE or to one of the other output formats KIWI supports like VMs, bootable USB and more.

The exact configuration of the systems running Spring XD will depend on the end goals, available infrastructure and a number of other things.  It seems like the Spring XD Admin node could be run on most infrastructure servers.  Factors such as reliability, stability and desired performance must also be considered when choosing hardware.

Q: Will Spring XD Admin run on a system with RaspberryPi like specs?

A: based on documentation, yes

Q: Will it run with good performance or reliably on such a system?

A: Probably not if being used for extended periods of time or for large amounts of traffic.

Comment: I do agree that properly sizing the machines running the components is a complicated question that requires analysis of the expected applications (or streams and jobs in the case of XD) that will run on the platform. However, there still are minimum requirements and I'm curious what they are. Can I run my admin processes with 128K of memory? Does it require disk space? etc...

Comment: I made some updates based on your comment above that would have been too long for the comment field.  Ultimately it depends on if this is a production, testing or development environment.  One advantage to using VMs for the Admin node and tasks would be that you can try different settings to figure out what is best based on your environment.  Without knowing more about how it is going to be used it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: Very helpful discussion. Do either of you know what kind of storage requirements there are?  I've done research into other big data tooling that says to use local storage due to the amount of I/O, but I haven't been able to find such a direct statement for Spring XD or ZooKeeper (still need to research Redis).

Comment: I tried starting Spring XD with a max heap set to 128k and it failed with OOM Error. I appreciate the detail given in your answer but I feel like it's not answering my simple question... Spring XD has a minimum hardware requirement to simply run; and I am asking what that is.